# How do I defrost frozen flour tortillas?

Tags: defrosting, tortilla, flour-tortilla

There is a wide variety of suggestions about how to thaw frozen flour tortillas.  What works best?

Comment: This is an odd question.. why freeze them? The fridge keeps them good for quite a long while without as much sacrifice to floppy goodness.

Comment: @zanlok As soon as I read the question title the answer, "don't freeze them to begin with" popped into my head. But I guess there could be cases where it would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are freezing the tortillas yourself and don't mind putting in a little extra work in the beginning to get more convenience later, I would separate the tortillas with waxed paper (actually I use the paper sheets that are waxed on one side, intended for bakeries).  What this buys you is the ability to pull out one or two tortillas as you need them.

They will defrost just fine in the pan that you are going to warm/brown them in anyway.

If you customarily run through a dozen tortillas, then you probably don't want to bother.  But if that is the case then you probably aren't freezing your tortillas in the first place.

Comment: The paper used in baking you are talking about is called parchment paper btw.

Answer (score 7):

I buy tortillas in bulk (36 to 48) at a time. I freeze them because even our family of 6 won't go through them fast enough if left in the refrigerator! I stack them with individual freezer wax paper between the tortillas (get them at warehouse stores such as costco) and then place in a plastic freezer bag or in a plastic storage container.  I THAW them in the microwave 6 at a time, papers removed, then wrapped in a SLIGHTLY damp kitchen towel. 30 seconds on high does it for the stack.

Comment: this is exactly my reason for freezing them, and how i freeze them, too. i separate them into stacks of 10, freeze them, and then vacuum seal them in fresh bags after that. a minute or so (at most!) in the microwave in a ziplock bag and they are like fresh again. our local stores sell them in stacks of 40-100 at a time (nothing fewer!), so freezing is the only way for me to go.

Answer (score 4):

The microwave is good for this sort of thing. Just wrap them in a towel to hold in steam and go for a couple minutes until they are soft. Or if you aren't too worried about plastic toxicity, you can put a few holes in the bag they came in and do it right in that.

Comment: Plastic toxicity, feh!

Comment: If it's a resealable bag, open it and holes (destroying the bag) could be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got the time, just put them (back) in the fridge for a couple of days.  I always keep some frozen (mostly because I have more room in the freezers than in the fridge).

Answer (score 1):

I put them directly on the stove burner and flip with tongs. Works great, they taste better this way.